# Virtual DAC sort

Tags: acumatica

I have a DAC that is defined only in a graph and is used to populate a grid.  I pull data from several locations in 3 different loops and then yield the final data to the IEnumerable.  Is there any way I can sort this DAC before the final yield?  I was looking around at the pxcache methods but I could not find the right answer.

Comment: did you try to define the sort on your view defnition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting is applied after you yield the DAC records using the DataView OrderBy clause.

```
public PXSelectOrderBy<DAC, OrderBy<DAC.sortField>> MyDataView;

public virtual IEnumerable myDataView()
{
   yield new DAC();
}
```

For filtered processing screens you can use PXFilteredProcessingOrderBy:

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXFilteredProcessingOrderBy<DAC, DACFilter, OrderBy<DAC.sortField>> MyDataView;

public virtual IEnumerable myDataView()
{
   yield new DAC();
}
```